# Removing modelsim error

Tags: verilog, error, modelsim

I am trying to simulate a simple inverter in verilog using modelsim 10.7 version. While compiling the code I am getting the -novopt error (error code 12110). As per user manual page 80; the -novopt argument is to be removed from vlog, vcom and vsim commands and from voptflow variable in the modelsim.ini file.

To remove the error, I set the voptflow variable to '0!' but could no find this argument for vlog, vcom and vsim commands. Pls. tell me how to go about solving the issue so that I dont get the error. I am attaching a snapshot of the error popup and my modelsim.ini file here.

Modelsim.ini file doenload link:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=88953175349637767605

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `-novopt` in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not using the -novopt option. I just installed the tool and tried the first simulation and ran into this error.It is most probably set as a default option and I am not able to remove it. I just want to run verilog and systemverilog codes. Pls. help.

Comment: Don't remember the GUI flow, but from command line you should be able to compile using `vlog -work work file_name.v` and then run `vsim work.file_name` for simulations.

Comment: Thanks @rvkrysh for your response. I am new to the tool and hence looking for the GUI option.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it references outdated software versions and unlikely to help other users.

Answer (score -1):

you should enable the vopt flow.
you can do that by going to view >> properties >> VHDL >>> and check the "use vopt flow" option.

[image]